# How to pull/extract all the content from a long list of urls with scrapy?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I would like to access and then extract the content's from a list of urls. For instance, consider this [website](https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/jjj?employment_type=2), I would like to extract the content of each post. So, based in the posted answers I tried the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib

class Test(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ["https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/jjj?employment_type=2"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/jjj?employment_type=2',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(response)
        links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('''.//a[@class='hdrlnk']''')
        links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in links]
        for x in links:
            print(x)
```

However, I do not understand how to scrap in a single movement all the content from a long list of links, without specifying the target urls... Any idea of how to do it?. I also try to something similar to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhYulVzYRng), and I am still stuck....

**UPDATE**
Based in @quasarseeker answer I tried:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from test.items import TestItems


class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):

name = "test"
allowed_domains = ["https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/jjj?employment_type=2"]
start_urls = (
                'https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/jjj?employment_type=2',
            )


rules = (  # Rule to parse through all pages
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=("//a[@class='button next']",)),
             follow=True),
        # Rule to parse through all listings on a page
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=("/p[@class='row']/a",)),
             callback="parse_obj", follow=True),)


    def parse_obj(self, response):
        item = TestItem()
        item['url'] = []
        for link in LinkExtractor(allow=(), deny=self.allowed_domains).extract_links(response):
            item['url'].append(link.url)
        print('\n\n\n\n**********************\n\n\n\n',item)
        return item
```

However, I am not getting anything:

```
2016-11-03 08:46:24 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.2.0 started (bot: test)
2016-11-03 08:46:24 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'test.spiders', 'BOT_NAME': 'test', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['test.spiders']}
2016-11-03 08:46:24 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats', 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2016-11-03 08:46:24 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-11-03 08:46:24 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-11-03 08:46:24 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-11-03 08:46:24 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-11-03 08:46:24 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-11-03 08:46:24 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://sfbay.craigslist.org/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-11-03 08:46:25 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/jjj?employment_type=2> (referer: None)
2016-11-03 08:46:25 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'sfbay.craigslist.org': <GET https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/jjj?employment_type=2&s=100>
2016-11-03 08:46:25 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-11-03 08:46:25 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 516,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 18481,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 3, 14, 46, 25, 230629),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'offsite/domains': 1,
 'offsite/filtered': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 3, 14, 46, 24, 258110)}
2016-11-03 08:46:25 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: get all tags `a` and for every `a` get `href` attrib.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Selenium (but BeautifulSoup) so there can be better solution.

You can get all `a` tags with class `hdrlnk` and then you can get `href` from this tags. Now you have list of all links and you can go to this pages and get content.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/jjj?employment_type=2')

# get all `a` with `class=hdrlnk`
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[@class="hdrlnk"]')
#links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.hdrlnk')
#links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hdrlnk')

# get all `href` from all `a`
links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in links]

# visit pages
for x in links:
    print(x)

    # follow link
    driver.get(x)

    # ... here get page content ...

    # ... EDIT ...

    # ... using `elements` (with `s`) ...
    #content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="postingbody"]')
    #content = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#postingbody')
    content = driver.find_elements_by_id('postingbody')
    #print([x.text for x in content])
    #print([x.text for x in content][0])
    print(''.join([x.text for x in content]))

    # ... using `element` (without `s`) ...
    #content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="postingbody"]')
    #content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#postingbody')
    content = driver.find_element_by_id('postingbody')
    print(content.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help furas!, I am getting the following exception: `AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'`. Any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: probably it is problem with `Firefox()` driver - use your driver: Chrome, PhantomJS, etc.

Comment: What about the content of the page?... could you provide some example of how to access to such content?...

Comment: use Chrome or Firefox to get `xpath` (like in video) and then use `find_element_by_xpath` (or others `find_element_by`) to get content.

Comment: I tried the following:` driver.get(x)
    content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''.//*[@id='postingbody']''')
    content = [y.get_attribute('postingbody') for y in content]
    for y in content:
        print(y)`

Comment: and I am getting: `TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not iterable`

Comment: there are `find_element_by` and `find_elements_by` - see `s` in second name - first returns only one element and it is not iterable, second returns always list (even if it finds only one element or nothing) and list is iterable.

Comment: i can't check page code now but `postingbody` is not attribute. attribute is `id`, `class`, `href`, `src`, etc. `postingbody` is value assigned to attribute `id`. I thing you need rather `y.text`.

Comment: What would be a better solution with beautifulsoup and scrapy?

Comment: @student see new code in answer. Because `id=postingbody` should be only one on page so you can use `element` (without `s`).

Answer (score -1):

This can be easily done with Scrapy. But you'll need to modify your rules and point the LinkExtractor to the xpath of all the pages you wish to scrape. In the web page you have provided in the example, it would look something like this:

```
 rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("//p[@class='row']/a")), \
                  callback='parse_obj', follow=True),)
```

This would enable the rules to parse through each listing which is contained in the xpath -

```
 /p[@class='row']/a
```

and then call upon parse_obj().

I also did notice that the listings page has pagination as well. In case you're looking to parse through every single page of the listing, you would need to include a rule to first parse through the pagination buttons, then through the links on each page and then finally call upon your function. Your code final would look something like this:

```
rules = (   #Rule to parse through all pages        
            Rule (LinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=("//a[@class='button next']",)),               
                follow= True),
            #Rule to parse through all listings on a page
            Rule (LinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=("//p[@class='row']/a",)), 
                callback="parse_obj" , follow= True),)
```

Comment: You'll need to use the CrawlSpider class for it to work by defining your class as Class Test(CrawlSpider) . 
In your case, it was looking for the default def parse() which we changed.

Read more upon it here -
[Scrapy Crawl Spider Docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)
and
[Blog Posts on Crawl Spiders](http://mherman.org/blog/2012/11/08/recursively-scraping-web-pages-with-scrapy/)

Comment: Thanks again!. Although, I read the information, I still can not figure out how to **scrap all the urls with scrapy**. Could you provide an example?.

Comment: Using the CrawlSpider, the rules define which Xpaths to parse through. You're directing the spider for the steps it should take from your start url to the destination url. 

In your target URL, you may just define the rules such that the spider enters all the xpaths which the structure : ' "/p[@class='row']/a" '. Once that 'step' is completed and spider visits the new page, you can define it to callback a function where you may parse all the information on that page.

The example code with the two rules I wrote in my answer should work for your aimed site.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, change your class from `Test(scrapy.Spider)` to `Test(CrawlSpider)`. Add this additional import too:
`from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule`
Also, `allowed_domains` should only contain the domain-name and not the page itself. The domain name here would be 'sfbay.craigslist.org'

Comment: Thank you for the help, I updated the content of the question... I did your recommendations. However I can not get the list of links..

Comment: Oops, seems like I missed a '/' in the xpath for the list of links.
The updated rules should read as `"//p[@class='row']/a"`

Comment: I tried again to run it with: ` scrapy crawl test -o file_test_cr_.csv` and nothing happens.